# How to display svg generated by javascript file as a component in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, svg

So, I need to  display a svg generated by this script. http://bl.ocks.org/andredumas/27c4a333b0e0813e093d . 
However I want to use it as a component in Angular 2. I couldn't find any solutions or any examples. Is this possible?

Also I'll need to talk with server and other components.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Please add your script to your question, links can be broken.

Answer (score 0):

The script your are referring to is using D3.

A good starting point for D3 and Angular 4 is:

https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts

Since every D3 chart is somewhat unique, it's hard to answer your question with an exact implementation, but the above framework should help you with the interaction between angular and D3.

I hope this points you in the right direction.